# Rails Unicorn Web Server Won't Start on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I can't get my app to successfully start at Heroku.  Here's the basics:

- Ruby 1.9.3p392 (when I run Ruby -v in my dev terminal this is what is returned, however the Heroku logs seem to indicate Ruby 2.0.0)
- Rails 3.2.13
- Unicorn Web Server
- Postgresql DB

I have deployed my app to Heroku but getting "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served."

Here's the final entries in the Heroku log:

```
+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

When I try to run Heroku ps, I get:

```
=== web (1X): `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
web.1: crashed 2013/06/22 17:31:22 (~ 6m ago)
```

I *think* it's possible the problem is stemming from this line in my app/config/application.rb

```
ENV.update YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))
```

This line is useful in dev to read my environment variables from my application.yml file. However, for security purposes I gitignore it from my repo and can see the Heroku logs complain that this file not being found.  For production, I have set my environment variables at Heroku via:

```
heroku config:add SECRET_TOKEN=a_really_long_number
```

Here's my app/config/unicorn.rb

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

And here's my Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Both my app/config/unicorn.rb and Procfile settings come from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn

Based on some IRC guidance, I installed Figaro, but alas that did not resolve the issue.

If you want to see the full app, it's posted at: https://github.com/mxstrand/mxspro

If you have guidance on what might be wrong or how I might troubleshoot further I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Heroku recently changed to using Ruby 2.0.0 as the default for new apps. To control this add `ruby '1.9.3'` into your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're spot on with you analysis. I've just pulled your code, made some tweaks and now have it started on Heroku.

My only changes;

`config/application.rb` - moved lines 12 & 13 to `config/environments/development.rb` - if you're using application.yml for development environment variables then keep it that way. Other option is to make line 13 conditional to your development environment with `if Rails.env.development?` at the end.

`config/environments/production.rb` - line 33 missing preceeding # mark

Comment: fyi: You have a pull request which addresses these issues. :)

Comment: John - thank you very much. Your fixes worked for me as well, very kind.  (I also needed to run a heroku run rake db:migrate).

Comment: @John Beynon, can you please specify what the contents of those lines you changed were, in case this Github repository is removed?

Comment: Linking to @JohnBeynon’s changes so his answer makes sense: https://github.com/mxstrand/mxspro/pull/1